# How Minitab calculate optimize number of bins of a normal distribution histogram

Tags: histogram, binning, minitab

I used minitab to draw a normal distribution histogram and saw that the number of bins in that graph doesn't follow any rules to calculate bin size that I know of (sturge, square-root, rice, freedman-diaconis, etc) but the bin size minitab generated is quite clean.

So I would like to know the work behind it.

Thanks for your help!

What I tried:
I have a data set of 22 values like so: 
[-2.33, -1.83, -1.73, -2.03, -2.03, -1.63, -1.73, -1.53, -1.93, -1.63, -2.23, -1.53, -2.13, -1.83, -2.33, -1.93, -1.73, -1.53, -1.63, -1.33, -1.73, - 1.33]

Then i used minitab to draw a graph and saw that it divide into 8 bars and round up the max-min value to like x.xx5 in each bin.
I tried to calculate with the above formula but couldn't get the same result.

Comment: After clicking around in Minitab a little bit they seem to be running something bespoke that always picks 5 times a power of 10 as the bin width. Since it's proprietary and not exactly extensively documented I'm not sure you'll get a real answer here, short of getting a developer to spill the beans or very painstakingly reverse-engineering the logic (because there must be *some* rule to it). You might be able to get something similar via R's `pretty()` or an algorithm like [this](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi25/25/cc/25p112.pdf).

Comment: Thanks you very much for your kindly provided references that helped me a lot! And you perhaps has any idea of how they calculate the number of bins? Thank you in advance! @PBulls

Comment: Not sure you can tell without knowing how they decide on the limits/bin widths (and in what order). I just went ahead and asked their tech support, got the following response: 'We use our own proprietary algorithm for determining the automatic histogram bins, and unfortunately cannot share its details.'.